# How to mock what Navigator.of(context).push() returns in a unit test?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, flutter-navigation

I'm writing a unit test for a function.

The structure of the function is the following:

```
final isUpdated = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed([route]);

if (isUpdated) {
    [update some global variables]
}
```

The global variables only change if the user returns from the next page by popping the Navigator with a `true` boolean value.

I don't want to check/verify if the push or the pop happened. I want to mock the `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()` call to return `true` in one test and `false` in another so that I can verify that the global variables get or don't get updated.

The test code I'm attempting to write would look like the this:

```
TEST 1 {

when: Navigator.pushNamed([route])
then answer: true

call function

expect: global variables to be updated
}


TEST 2 {

when: Navigator.pushNamed([route])
then answer: false

call function

expect: global variables to NOT be updated
}
```

I have looked this up a lot and haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what you are saying, you can simply do isUpdated = true in one test and isUpdated = false in another.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes but that wouldn't be properly mocking the ```pushNamed()``` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to pump 2 button widgets in the test, the first calling the function we are testing and the second containing `Navigator.of(context).pop()` call. The second should match whatever route is used in the function's `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed([route])`.

Here's a code snippet to clarify:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('test function', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build the widget that contains the button
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == "[route name used in function's pushNamed()]") {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage());
        }
        return null;
      },
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Go to Second Page'),
            onPressed: () {
              // call function that's being tested here
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));

    // Tap the button to navigate to the SecondPage
    await tester.tap(find.text('Go to Second Page'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Tap the button to go back to the home page
    await tester.tap(find.text('Go Back'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // add expect() here to check if the global variables were updated or not
  });
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Go Back'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.of(context).pop(true); test 1
            // Navigator.of(context).pop(); test 2
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```